# Apache tika behavior: misidentifies plain text as rtf, when filename has rtf extension

Tags: text, mime-types, rtf, apache-tika

I am new to Apache Tika.  I am using:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the only tika code I am loading.

Here is wrapper method I wrote to detect content type based on filecontent and filename.

```
    public static String detect(String fileContent, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (null == fileContent) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filecontent is required.");
        }

        Metadata meta = new Metadata();
        if (null != fileName) {
            meta.set(TikaCoreProperties.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
        }

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        return new Tika().detect(in, meta);
    }
```

If I pass a plain text string, and a filename with .rtf extension, Tika says that the content type is application/rtf.

If I pass the same string, and a filename with .pdf extension, Tika correctly says that the content is plain text.

This seems inconsistent to me.  In both cases, the string lacks magic numbers that would indicate either rtf or pdf content.  In the .rtf case it trusts the extension and ignores the absence of magic number, while but in the .pdf case it trusts the absence of magic number, and ignores the file extension.

Or at least that it how I understand it.  What am I missing?

-- Dave

Comment: If you want detection only from Magic, don't pass in a filename

Comment: I agree with @Gagravarr. As background, Tika does magic detection first, and if the file extension is a specialization of the magic detection, then it relies on the file extension. Tika's mime definition for RTF identifies RTF as a subclass of text/plain.